# My script use more memory to run

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I used some codes to limit displaying characters from a paragraph in a while loop.

This is my code:

```
//mysqli_stmt_fetch ($stmt);    
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

      $position=70; // Define how many characters you want to display.      
      // Find what is the last character.
      $subject = substr($subjects,$position,1);

      if($subject !=" "){
         while($subject !=" "){
            $i=1;
            $position=$position+$i;
            $subject = substr($subjects,$position,1); 
         }
      }     
      $subject = substr($subjects,0,$position); 

      echo '<h4><span>Subjects / </span>'.$subject.'.....</h4>';   
}
```

My problem is when running this script it take long time to run. If I discrease $position's value then executing script quickly and if I increase $position's value it take long time to execute.

if its `$position=80` I can't get it to work. Actually its not executing at all. My windows Task Manager display it is using Physical Memory 100%.

Can anybody tell me what is the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop. You could just count the number of spaces, maybe after `trim($subject)`, then substring after backing out or adding the number of spaces (adding, probably).

Comment: Can you show me it with an example? Thank you

Comment: You should check if ($subject !== false)

Comment: Hmm... There's a wrinkle I see with counting the spaces before substring'ing; you get the full count. Hmm.

Comment: I changed my IF condition like that but still it take long time to execute. when it is $position=80 there is an error message too.

Comment: This is the error message : Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\myweb\search.php on line 218

Comment: That's either due to a very loooong list of subjects (wherever that comes from), or the `while` is an infinite loop (never exits). It's not clear what you're trying to do with `$subject` and `$position`. Can you briefly give a description what that's meant to do on output?

Comment: $position variable use to display how many characters I need to display on the paragraph.

Comment: $subject variable has my paragraph

Comment: You are not handling the case when `$subjects` is shorter than 70 characters (in which case your code gets stuck at `while($subject !=" ")`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wish to return first 70 characters of string, but cut it off at the first space character.

You could use this:

```
function get_snippet($subject, $count) {

    // if string length is already under the desired char count
    if (strlen($subject) <= $count) return $subject;

    // find first space char after desired position
    $pos = strpos($subject, ' ', $count);

    if ($pos === false) return $subject;   // no space, must be end of the string so return entire text
    else return substr($subject, 0, $pos) . '...'; // return all chars up to first space
}
```

Calling it:

```
$newtext = get_snippet($subjects, 70);
```

Comment: If `$pos === false`, it might be reasonable to return only the part up to the last space before the cutoff point.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan Yes, I edited the code to return '...' when text is cutoff.